# How to highlight gridview row based on column value using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

- I want to highlight gridview Row for max id_column.I got it using codebehind logic.
- It is possible to do it using client-side-script?
- Please help

**ASP.NET**

```
 public void Bind_grid(ref DataTable DT, ref GridView GRID)
        {
            GRID.DataSource =  DT;
            GRID.DataBind();
            if (DT.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                msg += "No DATA Found \\n";
            }
            else
            {
                var maxVal = DT.AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<int>("ts_id"));
                DataRow[] rows = DT.Select("ts_id = '" + maxVal + "'");
                int updat_row = DT.Rows.IndexOf(rows[0]);
                GRID.Rows[updat_row].BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
            }     
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you need to do something like following. 
To access the column based on which we need to decide the color of the row, you can add a class to the field inside item template(see the aspx code). This class will be used to select all the controls, so that we can loop into it and check the value of the control.

Here is a simple gridview with just one column and a hidden field which stores the maxvalue

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="maxValForGrid" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BorderColor="Red" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="testfield" CssClass="idcol" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the sample server code which creates a datatable and sets it as datasource of the grid.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id",typeof(Int32)));
   DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
   row[0] = "1";
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
   row = dt.NewRow();
   row[0] = "2";
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
   row = dt.NewRow();
   row[0] = "2";
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
   maxValForGrid.Value = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(r => r.Field<int>("Id")).ToString();
   gridview1.DataSource = dt;
   gridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

And here is the javascript which does the job

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var maxVal = $("#maxValForGrid").val();
        $(".idcol").each(function () { 
            if($(this).text() === maxVal){
                $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color", "Plum");
            }  
        }); 
    });
```

And sample output

[image: Sample output]